# What caused the death of Superman?

Tags: dc, superman, super-hero

I have spotted a picture in the [Superman Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman).

[image: Superman dead in Lois Lane's arms]

And it was noted:

> Superman dies in Lois Lane's arms: *Superman* No. 75 (vol. 2, January 1993); Art by Dan Jurgens and Brett Breeding

However, I haven't found any answer in this article. So my question: which incident caused Superman to die? Is it true in the orthodox story series?

Comment: Lots of things "kill" superman. Often a superman death scene on the cover of a comic is just a trap to get you to buy it. Doomsday kills him at least a few times.

Comment: @GorchestopherH: really? Source?

Comment: Downvoted - not because it's a bad question, but because there was a clear lack of research effort.

Comment: Check out Max Landis' fantastic "The Death and Return of Superman" video, for a rather humoristic and bitter rant about it. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PlwDbSYicM

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Thanks to your link.

Comment: @phantom42 It's been established that the amount of research effort required for posting on this site is "to ponder to ones self for 10 to 20 seconds". http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2400/should-we-burninate-general-reference

Comment: @GorchestopherH, Yes, and that's why I didn't dare VTC. But the consensus was that if it showed little research effort, it was to be downvoted. Not only does searching for "superman 75 death" bring up the information, but the very Wikipedia article popopo sourced for the question links to it! That just edges the boundary of "research effort" too close to me.

Comment: @phantom42 Oh, I'm not saying you were wrong in anything you did, just making an observation I find humorous. Shockingly it's also been discussed that some may not be able to read Wikipedia or follow links as well as others, and therefore the following of said links constitutes expert or authoritative insight.

Comment: The text in Paul's answer is *literally right next* to the image in the question.  This is the perfect example of a too localized question.

Comment: @phantom42 Do you disagree with [NKCampbell here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/199340) please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've missed this paragraph in [the "Fictional character biography" section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman#Fictional_character_biography):

> In 1992 Superman was killed by the villain Doomsday, although the character was soon resurrected the following year.

This occurred in the storyline "[The Death of Superman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_Superman)", which did indeed occur in the mainstream continuity of the comic. Doomsday and Superman essentially beat each other to death.

Earlier, there was [a short "what-if?"-style story imagining the death of Superman](http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2011/09/01/silver-age-september-the-first-death-of-superman/), but that's not canon.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 6):

That picture specifically is from [The Death of Superman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_Superman) story arc, where he is killed by [Doomsday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_%28comics%29) (who also dies from his wounds inflicted by Superman).